# How can LDAP/Active Directory be integrated in WordPress?

Tags: authentication

I know there are a few plugins.  I need to more than likely roll my own.  But, I don't know enough about the WP security infrastructure.  Where does WP authorization and authentication code go?  I'm not really asking about a broad spectrum here, just a very basic answer to where the code is to begin editing so it looks at my AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing is to learn as much as you can from the available plugins even if they are not a perfect match to your requirements. This will help you identify areas of functionality which you will need to handle.

As for coding itself, for the authentication part you will most likely need to override the `authenticate` filter which lets you do user/password authentication before wordpress tries by itself.

Authorization can be a complex beast and I am not sure what kind of it you will need so can't even guess what will be useful. You most likely will need to get familiar with user roles and permissions.